# Tastypie filtering with multiple values

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I had a simple question on filtering in tastypie.

I want to filter with multiple values. For example:

`/api/v1/message/?accountId=1,5,12`

This doesnt work. Any idea how i can do this?

Do i need to use advanced filtering? If yes, how do I go about creating such a filter? A simple effortless example of puesdo-code would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hmm,

You can do this:

`/api/v1/message/?accountId__in=1&accountId__in=5&accountId__in=12`

PS: in filtering meta attribute, add `{'accountId': ALL}`

Comment: Thanks this works :) but it is going to make the url really long. Is there a way i can do this more neatly in case i need to filter for many account ids?

Comment: does this not overwrite the previous GET param?

Comment: @Amyth Just checked, it does not if you use the '__in' tool. It does if you write /api/v1/message/?accountId=1&accountId=5&accountId=12

Comment: When I do this, it just filters to the first `accountId` and omits the second. Maybe the behavior has changed.  wobbily_col's answer below works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 10):

The most recent version seems to work pretty easily - just use an "__in":

```
/api/v1/message/?accountId__in=1,5,12
```

(I assume you will need an entry in your resources Meta class, filtering = { 'accountId' : ALL })

Answer (score 9):

You'll have to build and apply a filter. Here's a small snippet, it's better to build the filter in build_filters, then apply it in apply_filters, but you'll get the idea

```
class Foo(ModelResource):

    # regular stuff goes here...

    def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
        base_object_list = super(Foo, self).apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)
        query = request.GET.get('query', None)
        ids = request.GET.get('ids', None)
        filters = {}
        if ids:
            ids = ids.replace('+', ' ').split(' ')
            filters.update(dict(id__in=ids))
        if query:
            qset = (
                Q(title__icontains=query, **filters) |
                Q(description__icontains=query, **filters)
            )
            base_object_list = base_object_list.filter(qset).distinct()
        return base_object_list.filter(**filters).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am having a hard time understanding how this would work. Is there something more that this :http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-filtering in the tastypie docs to help with this?

Answer (score 3):

`/api/v1/message/?accountId__in=1,5,12`
this is the right way to me, it is easy and straightforward.

`/api/v1/message/?accountId__in=1&accountId__in=5&accountId__in=12`
this way is strange and looks ugly.

of course, you need to add  `filtering = { 'accountId' : ALL }` in the resource META.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the **filtering** columns in **class Meta**. This is a *security by obscurity* rule.

So, the **accountId__in=[..]** rule is one of these.

```
filtering = { 'accountId' : ALL }
OR
filtering = { 'accountId' : [ ..., 'in' ] }

```