# Combining filters into one query in Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django Tastypie Advanced Filtering: How to do complex lookups with Q objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021749/django-tastypie-advanced-filtering-how-to-do-complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

I have a tastypie modelRseource that looks like this:

```
class TaggedResource(ModelResource):
    tags = ListField()
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserProfileResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Media.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
        authorization = MediaAuthorization()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete','patch']

    filtering = {
        #'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        #exact is date, lt is less than lte less than equal to, etc
        'timestamp': ['exact', 'range', 'lt', 'lte', 'gte', 'gt'],
        'social_source': ALL,
        'media_type': ALL,
        'comment': ['exact', 'startswith', 'endswith', 'contains'],
        'media_text': ['exact', 'startswith', 'endswith', 'contains'],
    }
```

I need to have an OR operator between filters and would love to combine the query into one parameter.  For example, I want to return objects that contain the word "test" filtering from the comment field OR media_text field.

This would be ideal:  http:mysite.com/api/v1/tagged?q=test

where 'q' performs an OR filter for both fields.

Is this doable?

UPDATE:  Here is what I am working on with advanced filters but am not really sure how to get an OR statement:

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    if filters is None:
        filters = {}

    orm_filters = super(TaggedResource, self).build_filters(filters)

    if 'q' in filters:
        orm_filters['comment__contains'] = filters['q']
        orm_filters['media_text__contains'] = filters['q'] 
    return orm_filters
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing the right thing by overriding build_filters, you can use django's Q class for AND/OR queries, I have answered a similar question here

[Tastypie filtering with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436229/tastypie-filtering-with-multiple-values/11438100#11438100)

and here's another interesting one:

[Tastypie Negation Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675127/tastypie-negation-filter)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at [Advanced Filtering](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-filtering) even though I' not sure it is doable. 
But if you override build_filters, you have access to the whole Resource and possible could define such filters which go across more than field.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into Advanced Filtering and really have no clue how I would do an OR statement.  What I have is filtering with an AND condition.

Comment: What I meant is you actually gona have to define your own filter, and then this is the place where you can added it to the tastypie filtering.

Comment: @bevinlorenzo you can use django's `Q` class to do an `OR` statement. It resides in `django.db.models.Q`. More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.Q