# how to query a set of random entries tastypie

Tags: tastypie

I have events module .my user favroite some of random events from listing  . i will  store them in favroite table of my database

```
id   module

1     events
5     events
9    events
2    business
```

now , my question how can i make a query to fetch 1,5,9 at single request for event ? is there any way to request it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can filter by id to get multiple events in one request, look at the selected answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436229/tastypie-filtering-with-multiple-values) to learn how to do that. Should work out of the box.